# Oracle - How to partition by case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Oracle SQL in a report that I inherited. The `bucket1_days_prc` and `overdue_prc` should show the percentage of the number of invoices that falls within those buckets based on the number of days overdue. I haven't worked with windowing functions in ages, so I can't figure out how to incorporate the `case` date range into the windowing function. Currently the value just divides by itself (although it apparently worked before) and always gives 100%. How can I identify the number of invoices that fall in the bucket for that `case` date range and divide it by the total number of invoices? The columns must basically repeat the answer or show null in order to work with BI Publisher (I hope).

```
select initcap(pv.vendor_name)                                                   vendor_name,
       aia.invoice_num                                                           invoice_number,
       aia.invoice_amount, 
       to_char(aia.invoice_received_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')                         invoice_received_date,
       to_char(aia.invoice_received_date + 30, 'DD-MON-YYYY')                    date_invoice_due_payment,
       (
          case 
             when (trunc(sysdate) - ((trunc(aia.invoice_received_date)) + 30)) < 0 then 0 
             else (trunc(sysdate) - ((trunc(aia.invoice_received_date)) + 30))
          end 
       )  days_late,
       (
          case   
             when round(trunc(sysdate) - (trunc(aia.invoice_received_date))) between 0 and 9 then
                aia.invoice_amount
          end
       )  bucket1_days,   
       (
          case   
             when round(trunc(sysdate) - (trunc(aia.invoice_received_date))) between 0 and 9 then
                sum(aia.invoice_amount) over (partition by pv.vendor_id order by pv.vendor_id) 
          end
       )  bucket1_days_sup,
       nvl
       (
          case   
             when round(trunc(sysdate) - (trunc(aia.invoice_received_date))) between 0 and 9 then                            
                count(aia.invoice_id) over (partition by null) / count(aia.invoice_id) over (partition by null) * 100
          end,
          0
       )  bucket1_days_prc,    
       (
          case   
             when round(trunc(sysdate) - (trunc(aia.invoice_received_date))) > 30 then
                aia.invoice_amount
          end
       )  overdue,
       (
          case   
             when round(trunc(sysdate) - (trunc(aia.invoice_received_date))) > 30 then
                sum(aia.invoice_amount) over (partition by pv.vendor_id order by pv.vendor_id) 
          end
       )  overdue_sup, 
       (
          case   
             when round(trunc(sysdate) - (trunc(aia.invoice_received_date))) > 30 then
                count(aia.invoice_id) over (partition by null) / count(invoice_id) over (partition by null)
          end
       )  overdue_prc, 
       sum(invoice_amount) over (partition by pv.vendor_id order by pv.vendor_id) total_per_supplier,
       count(1)            over (partition by pv.vendor_id order by pv.vendor_id) inv_per_supplier,
       count(invoice_id)   over (partition by null) total_inv_cnt,
       sum(invoice_amount) over (partition by null) total_inv_amt,
       (sum(invoice_amount)   over (partition by pv.vendor_id order by pv.vendor_id) / sum(invoice_amount)   over (partition by null)) * 100 total_perc_amt,
       (count(invoice_amount) over (partition by pv.vendor_id order by pv.vendor_id) / count(invoice_amount) over (partition by null)) * 100 total_perc_cnt
from   apps.ap_invoices_all aia,
       apps.gl_periods  gp,
       apps.po_vendors  pv
where  aia.payment_status_flag = 'N'
and    aia.cancelled_date is null
and    (trunc(sysdate) - ((aia.invoice_received_date))) > 0
and    upper(gp.period_name) = upper(to_char(aia.invoice_received_date, 'MON-YY')) 
and    pv.vendor_id = aia.vendor_id        
order  by 2
```

The percentage of data in each bucket is needed, so if there is two invoices out of four total in the 0-9 days bucket then that would be 50%.

Sample data and expected output

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  A clear explanation of your problem in the context of the data would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it with:

```
sum
(
 case   
     when round(trunc(sysdate) - (trunc(aia.invoice_received_date))) between 28 and 30 then 1
     else 0 
 end
)  over (partition by null) / sum(1) over (partition by null) bucket7_days_cnt,
```